# Python - How to output the player with the highest score and their name

Tags: python, variables

I want to do is find who has the most points and output their name.

```
name1 = (input("Give me a name"))
name2 = (input("Give me a name"))
name3 = (input("Give me a name"))

point1 = (input("Give me your points "+name1))
point2 = (input("Give me your points "+name2))
point3 = (input("Give me your points "+name3))

score = [point1, point2, point3]

highscore = (max(highscore))
```

However, all I can do with this program is print the highest score. How do I print the name, as well?

Comment: sure just make them tuples instead or even dictionaries

Comment: You are not using *arrays* you are using a `list` object.

Comment: Please don't take this as an offence but maybe it would be wiser to first work through a good beginner's book instead of trying to be taught on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix from here is to put them into corresponding lists:

```
name_list = [name1, name2, name3]
score_list = [score1, score2, score3]

# Now, get the best score, its position in the list,
#   and the corresponding name
best_score = max(score_list)
best_idx = score_list.index(best_score)
best_name = name_list[best_idx]
```

This is not the "best" way; that would have a single list of 2-tuples, or a dictionary to hold the scores and names.  I leave that to the student, once you understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a dictionary of players to their points and use `max`'s `key` argument.

```
# Get dictionary: dictionary = {"name1": points1, "name2": points2...}
name = max(dictionary, key = lambda name: dictionary[name])
points = dictionary[name]
```

What this does is call the `key` function to determine the value of each thing, instead of just taking their normal value.

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution would be, if you would save the highscores in a Dictionary with Player as the key and the `score` as the value.

```
import operator
x = {"PlayerA":120, "PlayerB":30, "PlayerC":40}
highest = max(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
print highest
>('PlayerA', 120)
```

That's of course to begin with, to really retrieve efficiently retrieve the highest elements there are more sophisticated data-structures that inserts `sorted`. You could use a list with the bisect method to maintain this

Answer (score 0):

You can zip them (like a zipper) - will truncate the result to the lenght of the shortest list:

```
name_list = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
score_list = [5,8,39,50,80] # 60 and 80 are discarded by zip as no match inname_list

zipped =  zip(score_list,name_list)
```

If you sort this list of tuples it will sort the list by each tuples first param, if they are identical it will sort those 2 by the second tuple param.:

```
sortZip = sorted(zipped) # https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

print(sortZip)
```

It is sorted ascending (you can specify otherwise, lookup sorted) - you get the last one by `sortZip[-1]` a list comprehension.

Output via:

```
# list[-1] == last element of the list
# tuple[0] == 1st element, tuple[1] == 2nd element
print("Max: ", sortZip[-1][0] , " points done by " , sortZip[-1][1])
```

gives:

```
Max:  39  points done by  name3
```